# Cell phone ringtone midi instrument pop music

Tags: sound-effects

Hello everyone,

I would like to know what's the best online resource for cell phone ring tones of pop music.  What I'm looking for are some "cheap midi instrument 8 bit phony lame versions of pop songs"...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I already produced a lot of phone sounds, using the international standards, frequencies.
I produced as well some ringtones , and recorded another one in my studio .
If you want to try my files i will be pleased to pack and send to you.
Best regards,
LeoSSom.